# LaTeX verse package no indent for the poem

Tags: indentation, verse

I am typesetting using the `verse` package. I have trouble getting what's inside the `verse` environment not to get indented.

In the minimal working example below, I would like the "Blessed are" to be aligned with "This is the regular text that is not indent."

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
Blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.\\
Blessed are those who mourn, for they shall be comforted.\\
Blessed are the meek, for they shall inherit the earth.\\
Blessed are those who hunger and thirst for righteousness, for they shall be satisfied.
\end{verse}
\noindent This is the regular text that is not indented. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I think you want the `flushleft` environment, rather than `verse`.

Answer (score 6):

For this, I would use the `alltt`-package together with `\normalfont` as mentioned in [the documentation of the `verse`-package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verse):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
Blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.\\
Blessed are those who mourn, for they shall be comforted.\\
Blessed are the meek, for they shall inherit the earth.\\
Blessed are those who hunger and thirst for righteousness, for they shall be satisfied.
\end{verse}    

\begin{alltt}\normalfont
Blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.
Blessed are those who mourn, for they shall be comforted.
Blessed are the meek, for they shall inherit the earth.
Blessed are those who hunger and thirst for righteousness, for they shall be satisfied.
\end{alltt}

\noindent This is the regular text that is not indented. 
\end{document}
```

This will even safe you from typing `\\` behind every line and will yield the following.

[image]

**Update**

In order to still be able to use the features of `verse`, you will have to redefine the left margin for the poems. If you want to do this globally, you could just write `\setlength{\leftmargini}{<some value>}`.
In my following MWE, I will just change for one verse and change it back to default afterwards.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\saveleftmargini} % define a temp variable for the original margin
\setlength{\saveleftmargini}{\leftmargini} % write the original margin in this variable
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em} % set the left margin to zero
\begin{verse}
Blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.\\
Blessed are those who mourn, for they shall be comforted.\\
Blessed are the meek, for they shall inherit the earth.\\
Blessed are those who hunger and thirst for righteousness, for they shall be satisfied.
\end{verse}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\saveleftmargini}% restore original value in case you do not want to change this thing globaly.

\begin{verse}
Blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.\\
Blessed are those who mourn, for they shall be comforted.\\
Blessed are the meek, for they shall inherit the earth.\\
Blessed are those who hunger and thirst for righteousness, for they shall be satisfied.
\end{verse}
\noindent This is the regular text that is not indented. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But unfortunately the `alltt` environment doesn't wrap around lines that are too long. I'm actually working with a half letterpaper paper size.

Comment: OK, your examples should always contain the complete problem you are heaving. The need for wrapping or the half letter is not visible in you OP and therefore made me guessing around.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: No need to say sorry. I am just giving tips how you will get much better answers in the future. Pls see my update. This should do what you want.